# Google Chrome "warn to quit" not warning on Cmd + Tab quit

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

As a Mac poweruser, I often use Cmd + Tab to switch between applications.  Tab is unfortunately close to Q, so I often end up jamming Cmd + Q as well by accident.  On most applications, this isn't a problem; a popup appears confirming if I want to quit, and I just click "cancel."

However, this isn't the case with Google Chrome.  I checked "warn before quitting", and when I press Cmd + Q a box saying "Hold Cmd + Q to quit" pops up.  But when jamming Cmd + Q while switching to Chrome using Cmd + Tab, it completely ignores the "warn before quitting" policy and quits immediately.

Any way to fix this annoyance?  Switching either of the shortcuts to something else would fix the problem, but I'm not able to find a way to do so.

Answer (score -1):

When Chrome is open, on the Menu bar on the very top of the screen, click "Chrome", then "Confirm to quit" (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>).

Comment: As I said in my question, I've already done this, but it doesn't nothing when I accidentally hit Cmd + Q while switching windows with Cmd + Tab.